# My WinXP Pro Doesn't See Galaxy S7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I've changed cables and USB ports, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

The My Computer/Hardware profile doesn't see the S7 at all.

Comment: I don't see it either – maybe my glasses are not good enough. Oh: as are your details :) Please add: Does it show up in the Windows device manager? Do you have the required drivers installed? For the USB ports checked: were all of them USB 3, or did you check on USB 2.0 ports as well?

Comment: Did you install the nessesary drivers for your device? If not, try that

Answer (score 4):

The Galaxy S7 uses MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) which is not natively supported in Windows XP. You need to install [Microsoft's Media Transfer Protocol Porting](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19153) Kit to enable Windows XP to use MPT.

Comment: FYI, the link is bad.

Comment: @Android Dev Fixed link

Comment: I installed the drivers and I installed the MTP. No change.
Thanks.

Comment: @villaproject then I'm sorry, without more information it's impossible to help you.